# Binding method to the button - thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to assign the Robot class method to the button using thymeleaf. In my controller I created my controller with the method

```
@GetMapping("/start")
public String test(Model theModel) {
    return "moveTheMouse";
}

boolean bool = true;


@RequestMapping("/move")
public String moveTheMouseMethod() throws Exception {
    
    Robot hal = new Robot();
    while(bool){
        hal.delay(1000 * 5);
        int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + 2;
        int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y+ 2;
        hal.mouseMove(x,y);   
    }
    
    return "moveTheMouse";
}
```

And I'm trying to assign it to the button in the html file, however it does not work

```
<a
  th:action ="@{/move}"
  class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    MOVE THE MOUSE
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a form to your application and set the action. So the code could look like this:

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/move}" method="get">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Or you can use `th:href` instead of the `th:action` for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of these:

i)

```
<a th:href ="@{move}" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        MOVE THE MOUSE
</a>
```

ii)

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/move}" method="GET">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```